# C# Can a custom control property inherit initial value from control container?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a custom control MyButton derived from Button, and added a Color property MyColor.
Can I make the initial value of MyColor be the ForeColor of MyButton container, just as happens with the ForeColor property?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to make `MyColor` an ambient property.

> An ambient property is a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent control

To do this, you use the `[AmbientValue]` attribute: this example is from [that attribute's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ambientvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) with a couple of missing bits filled in:

```
[AmbientValue(typeof(Color), "Empty")]
[Category("Appearance")]
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White")]
[Description("The color used for painting alert text.")]
public Color AlertForeColor
{
    get
    {
        if (this.alertForeColorValue == Color.Empty &&
            this.Parent != null)
        {
            return Parent.ForeColor;
        }

        return this.alertForeColorValue;
    }

    set
    {
        this.alertForeColorValue = value;
    }
}

private static Color defaultAlertForeColorValue = Color.White;

private static Color ambientColorValue = Color.Empty;

// This method is used by designers to enable resetting the
// property to its default value.
public void ResetAlertForeColor()
{
    this.AlertForeColor = AttributesDemoControl.defaultAlertForeColorValue;
}

// This method indicates to designers whether the property
// value is different from the ambient value, in which case
// the designer should persist the value.
private bool ShouldSerializeAlertForeColor()
{
    return (this.alertForeColorValue != AttributesDemoControl.ambientColorValue);
}
```